# How to erase last char in console using backspace, without using space char?

Tags: c, console, console-application

I'm trying to implement a console program that has backspace functionality. The console accepts a number of valid commands I've defined. Example:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I'm using a switch statement, which checks the current char returned by `getchar()`.

```
    switch (inChar)
    {
        case '\r':
        case '\n':
        {
            ...
        }

        case 0x18:                      // ^x
        {
            ...
        }

        case 0x08:                     // backspace
        {
            printf("\b \b");
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            inBuffer[inBufIndx++] = inChar;
            inBuffer[inBufIndx] = 0;
            printf("%c", inChar);       // echo character
        }
    }
```

The code above gives the appearance of erasing the character, but places a space char. This works for most instances, such as erasing the `o` off of `helo` but does not work when erasing the `o` off `helpo`. My shell can no longer interpret the command due to the space char that is printed in the place of the `o`

How can I implement backspace for chars at the end of the inputthat need to be erased?

**EDIT:** rici is exactly right. I was not removing the char I erased in the console from my inBuffer. The code below gave the desired functionality.

```
        case 0x08:
        {
            printf("\b \b");
            inBuffer[inBufIndx--] = NULL;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Why just `printf("\b")` is not enough?

Comment: I tried `printf("/b")`, but that just moved the cursor back one char and did not erase the unwanted char. The code above moves the cursor back, prints a space over the unwanted char, then moves the cursor back again so that I can rewrite over the space.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to remove trailing spaces from command strings before attempting to execute them.

Comment: Console control is not part of the C standard. Too borad, it depends on your console, etc. There is no standard way.

Comment: From a fellow CS345 student from the future, I, and my Jurassic Park, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you need to remove the character from `inBuffer` (by decrementing `inBufIdx` and overwriting the old character with a `0`). What the screen shows should be irrelevant.

By the way, the backspace-space-backspace sequence won't work at the right margin

Answer (score 0):

@Eugene Sh. answer worked for me, but just without the round braces in my tcsh shell:
printf "\b"